# Dual of sum of two sigmoid functions

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

Suppose we have 2 samples with features $\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2 \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and there is an uncertain parameter $\mathbf{\theta} \in \mathbb{R}^d$. Also, let's define $\mu(y)$ as a sigmoid/logistic function, i.e., $\mu(y)=1/(1+\exp(-y))$. I am wondering how it is possible to write the dual of the following problem.
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\min_{\theta} \: &\left\{ a_1 \mu(\mathbf{x}_1^T \theta)+a_2\mu(\mathbf{x}_2^T \theta) \right\}
\\
& \|\theta-\hat{\theta}\|_{H} \le \gamma
\end{split}
\end{equation}

It is assumed that $a_1,a_2, \gamma>0$ and $H$ is positive definite.
I know how to solve it when there is just one sample, but I am confused when there are two samples, and I am wondering how to extend it to the case when there are more samples, $n>2$.
Is there any condition to write its dual? Since vectors $\mathbf{x}_i$ are feature vectors, it is possible to transform them into any interval.

Also, it is possible to find the dual of the following problem?
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\min_{\theta} \: &\left\{ a_1 \mu(\mathbf{x}_1^T \theta)-a_2\mu(\mathbf{x}_2^T \theta) \right\}
\\
& \|\theta-\hat{\theta}\|_{H} \le \gamma
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Finally, is it possible to extend it to other generalized linear models?
Thanks

Comment: [How to find robust counterpart of sum of logit functions?](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/9146/491)

Comment: It is my own question but I don't know how to link them. I also mentioned it in the other question.

Comment: No worries!  You can't "link questions" formally across different SE sites, but you are supposed to disclose crossposting.  I didn't downvote;  just posted for others' awareness.  Note:  [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/476162)